# CSRF Cookie not set when posting request with AngularJs - Django Backend

Tags: angularjs, ajax, django, post, csrf

I'm building a web app with angularjs and django and I'm submitting form via Ajax request.

My problem is that when posting an Ajxa request with angular (ng-file-upload precisely) the csrfmiddlewaretoken expected by django is not set.

From my lectures on angular documentation and other forums I ended up with the following configuration.

In the config part of angular :

```
$httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
$httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

and in my controller the code for sending the request is :

```
Upload.upload({
                url: 'http://localhost:8000/image',
                headers: {
                  'X-CSRFToken': $cookies['csrftoken']
                },
                data: {file: file}
            })
```

With that code the request send has the following headers :

```
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,de;q=0.2,fi;q=0.2
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:16582
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarybWo821vSwcejTATP
Cookie:csrftoken=bC2UpXurGXAg3AUZgSqMVlUs8TKfussS
Host:localhost:8000
Origin:http://127.0.0.1:8000
Referer:http://127.0.0.1:8000/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.80 Safari/537.36
X-CSRFToken:UeSt4LoqgU9L28JQBdVbS2IJJXOMQK6n
```

However for django to be able to handle csrf protection correctly the following header is missing

```
Cookie:_ga=GA1.1.1358238168.1447425523; XSRF-TOKEN=zWIM6q7O2Nz3PLm8TMUJSLFVRF8bKUbr; csrftoken=UeSt4LoqgU9L28JQBdVbS2IJJXOMQK6n
```

So far and despite having seen a lot of forums about this topic I didn't manage to set this header. if I try to set it programmatically via :

```
Upload.upload({
                url: 'http://localhost:8000/image',
                headers: {
                  'Cookie': 'csrftoken='+$cookies['csrftoken']
                },
                data: {file: file}
            })
```

I end up with the following error in my console :

```
Refused to set unsafe header "Cookie"
```

My problem is really how to configure the cookie header from the client side. My django code is fine.

I have been struggling with this for quite a time now. Any help would be appreciated ! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you added in the csrftoken to client headers: `{'X-CSRFToken': $cookies['csrftoken']}` means your client is most probably ready, but for security matter if you interact with django api from external application he will still block the request  returning **unsafe header "Cookie"**.
try the following configuration to allow the cross site request over your app:

```
pip install django-cors-headers
```

and then add it to your installed apps in your **settings.py**:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
...
'corsheaders',
...
)
```

You will also need to add a middleware class to listen in on responses and make sure you respect the order as follow:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
...
'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
...
)
```

and finally add this settings variable:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

This should be enough but for more customized configuration you can check [django-cors-headers](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers)